# Does OpenSSL have stat for read change cipher spec (SSL3_ST_CR_CHANGE_A)

Tags: tls, openssl

In EAP-TLS method of authentication if a server sends Change Cipher Spec message to  the client, I couldn't find references to `SSL3_ST_CR_CHANGE_A`.  The enum is defined for `SSL3_ST_CR_CHANGE_A` in `ssl3.h`, but I looked at OpenSSL's source code: `s3_clnt.c:ssl3_connect()`, and I don't see any case that handles it.

The openssl version which I am using is openssl-1.0.1e, does any other version supports this.

Answer (score 1):

The `change_cipher_spec` message is not a handshake message; it has its own special record type. It is handled in `s3_pkt.c:ssl3_read_bytes()`.

OpenSSL handles the handshake as a state machine; the `state` variable contains the current status. Whenever a handshake message is received, the status changes. The `change_cipher_spec` message, being always small (its length is 1 byte, exactly), is handled on-the-fly just like an alert message. When received, it does not change the `state` variable, but instead sets the `change_cipher_spec` field to 1. When a `change_cipher_spec` is expected, the next message should be a `Finished`, and the code processing the `Finished` message checks the `change_cipher_spec` field.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Actually i did not get any log saying that it has processed the change spec thats took me confusion.

Comment: Once the expected finish processed i received another client_hello_requset in the same handshake as a encrypted message, and openssl able to decrypt it and it is wrting client_hello into the buffer, but i am getting zero bytes from BIO_read and getting error saying that "Failed to read possible Application Data error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)" the ultimate issue which i am seeing is that once if it received finish then BIO_read simply return zero. what could be the issue ?